# Hide "New Site" on Site Actions menu?

Tags: custom-actions

Using SharePoint 2010, how do I remove "New Site" from the Site Actions menu.  I believe I can do this through permissions but would like to remove for all users (and replace with a custom action link).

Oddly, this is much more difficult than expected.  I can apparently use HideCustomAction for some of the items but New Site seems to be a problem.

thx

Comment: So I figured out that the Site Action options are in the master page for the site.  I can also edit the master page to remove that menu option or change the click event for it.

I would like to remove/hide or change this menu option through a feature however.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

This was tough when I started doing it today. It is possible via feature using a CustomAction element in the elements.xml and some code. I tried a no-code solution but it was not possible.

```
 <CustomAction
        Id="HideCreateSiteInSiteActions"
        Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
        GroupId="SiteActions"
        Sequence="901"
        Title="Publishing SiteActions Menu Customization"
        ControlAssembly="Your Assembly full name"        ControlClass="your class full name">
  </CustomAction>
```

Following code would go in class:

```
public class YourClassName : WebControl
    {
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            var siteActions = ToolBarMenuButton.GetMenuControl(this);
            siteActions.MenuControl.PreRender += (o, args) =>
            {
                var targetMenu = siteActions.GetMenuItem("MenuItem_CreateSite");
                if (targetMenu == null) return;
                siteActions.MenuControl.HiddenMenuItems.Add(targetMenu);
            };
        }        
    }
```

The scope of your feature would be "site". Also, don't forget to put SafeControl entry for your class in the web.config or it may not work.