# SP2010 Remove options from the Site Actions Menu

Tags: development, ecb-menu

For a publishing site, I'm able to add Custom Actions to the site actions menu.
Now I would like to hide all the default ones (except Edit Page).
I tried to do this with the HideCustomAction Element but this doesn't seam to work.

In a publishing site I like to hide:

-New page ( * ) 
-New document Library 
-new Site
-More Options

-Manage Content and Structure ( * )
-View all site content
-Edit in SharePoint Designer
-Site Permissions
-Site Settings

Removing them in the master page or using the security trimmed parameter is not realy an option since I could still see (*)

Answer (score 1):

While it might be possible with JavaScript (and a sprinkle of jQuery if you like) you most likely end up like me writing a .NET WebControl to accomplish that task as using the HideCustomActionElement and masterpage tweaking methods do have some gotchas with SharePoint publishing features enabled.

To get started check out this thread [Hide "New Site" on Site Actions menu?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6799/hide-new-site-on-site-actions-menu)

Answer (score 1):

r you interested using jquery? If you want to than just check below script in your console Is this work or not.

try this :

```
  $("[id*=SiteActionsMenu]").bind('click',function(){

   var i = 0;
   $('.ms-MenuUIPopupScreen').height('auto');
   $('.ms-MenuUIPopupInner').height('auto');
   $('.ms-MenuUIPopupInner').find('li').each(function(){
          if(i != 0)
            {
              $(this).hide();
            }
       i++;
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could accomplish it with the [HideCustomActionElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790.aspx) with a custom Feature.

Comment: As mentioned I tried this but for some reason it doesn't work<br> <br><HideCustomAction<br> Id="HideCreatePublishingPage"<br>GroupId="SiteActions"<br> HideActionId="PublishingSiteActionsMenuCustomizer"<br> Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"> </HideCustomAction>

Comment: Did you deploy this HideCustomAction with a feature scoped for Web and did you make sure the feature is activated?

Comment: I did even site scoped... And my custom actions that I add work fine