# How to hide new site option in feature is activated event

Tags: sharepoint-server, feature

How to hide new site option in feature is activated event. when feature is deactivated it will visible to users

Comment: You mean hide the option to create new subsite?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are in?

Comment: 2010 , yes we need to hide new site option when feature activated event receiver

Answer (score 0):

You can add following custom action:

```
<CustomAction
    Id="HideCreateSiteInSiteActions"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    GroupId="SiteActions"
    Sequence="901"
    Title="Publishing SiteActions Menu Customization"
    ControlAssembly="Your Assembly full name"        ControlClass="your class full name">
```

And following code in the Class file:

```
public class YourClassName : WebControl
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        var siteActions = ToolBarMenuButton.GetMenuControl(this);
        siteActions.MenuControl.PreRender += (o, args) =>
        {
            var targetMenu = siteActions.GetMenuItem("MenuItem_CreateSite");
            if (targetMenu == null) return;
            siteActions.MenuControl.HiddenMenuItems.Add(targetMenu);
        };
    }        
}
```

[Reference link here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6799/hide-new-site-on-site-actions-menu)